# Nested ScrollView block parent scroll when started scrolling in child

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have a React Native app with a parent ScrollView component that wraps other 2 ScrollViews that are siblings. How could I force the parent to only scroll when I've started scrolling from outside the child components?

**Current behavior:**

> When I start scrolling in a child, the child scrolls, but when the list reaches the end, the parent starts scrolling (finger was not removed from the screen, so it was the same scrolling action).

**Desired behavior:**

> When I start scrolling in a child, the child scrolls, but when the list reaches the end, the parent does NOT scroll until I interrupt the current scrolling action and start scrolling again from the area of the parent.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @denistepp I didn't find a simple one, and I didn't try to find a more complex one so I managed the data differently. sorry mate

Comment: I figured it out by adding ListHeaderComponent. Not sure if it would be helpful but you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77307956/child-flatlist-scrolls-parent-flatlist-when-it-reaches-the-end/77308034#77308034

Answer (score 0):

```
export const ScrollEnabledContext = createContext(null);

const Parent = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const setIsEnabled = (bool) => {
        ref.current?.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: bool });
    };

    return (
        <ScrollEnabledContext.Provider value={setIsEnabled}>
            <ScrollView ref={ref} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
                <ChildScrollView />
            </ScrollView>
        </ScrollEnabledContext.Provider>
    );
};

const ChildScrollView = () => {
    const value = useContext(ScrollEnabledContext);

    return (
        <ScrollView onTouchStart={() => value(false)} onTouchEnd={() => value(true)}>
            ....
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't have nested scroll views in the same direction. You can try to improve the UI.
Even for the user this can be confusing.
Send a screenshot, so people can better understand what the goal is.

Comment: The design is quite easy to understand and therefore not confusing. I cannot change it, it's not up to me.

Comment: You can try to use a combination of scrollEnabled, onScrollBeginDrag and onScrollEndDrag. So you could disable one during the use of the other.