# Child Flatlist Scrolls Parent Flatlist when it reaches the end

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

I have following implementation in my RN component:

```
const renderItem = ({item}:{item: any}) => {
  return (
   <>
    <FlatList 
      horizontal
      renderItem={renderItem}
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      style={{width: screen.width}}
    />
    <...OtherComponents/>
   </>
  )
}

<FlatList 
  pagingEnabled
  horizontal
  renderItem={renderItem}
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
/>
```

The thing is that each child in the parent Flatlist is styled to take full width of the screen so when i scroll the data from parent i can see the other lists (getItemLayout and viewability configs are ignored here).

The problem arises when I get to the end of the child flatlist: it starts to scroll the parent too. How to prevent it? Using states on callbacks like `onBeginDrag` and others does not work.

here is the sample snack: https://snack.expo.dev/C_F6ci0g3?platform=ios

similar question: [Nested ScrollView block parent scroll when started scrolling in child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219806/nested-scrollview-block-parent-scroll-when-started-scrolling-in-child)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by adding a horizontal (nested) list as  `<ListHeaderComponent />`. It does not scroll the parent list even when it reaches the end.